# Is it possible to cook with low power PV systems (under 300 W)

Tags: photovoltaics, consumer-electronics, home-improvement

This topic is slightly related to [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/electronics-used-for-cooking), with some extra details.

I would like to go off-grid and therefore buy a PV kit. I can see that the prices for PV systems with a power of +3kW are very high, so I was thinking how much I can get from a 300-500W system, which is way cheaper. The fridge, the PC, and other households can easily work with such a power if stored in batteries, but the problem is the stove.

My current stove has a power between 1 and 2 kW, which means that I would need to have this instant power from the PV or have it stored in some batteries. This instant power is of course not available, but I can get more batteries to store let's say at least 1-2kWh of energy, which also costs a lot.

The only thing that I have in mind is to find a stove/oven that has a low power (under 300W). Is the crock pot the only option for this? I would like to use the stove/oven for cooking different dishes, including frying and baking. Any idea if a "standard" 1-2kW oven can be modified to work with lower power? Or does any of you have any other idea how to cook with such a little power?

Comment: Have you considered a propane tank & gas stove?   If you insist on all-electric, then you will have to balance total system cost (PV, battery (see Tesla wall pack), converters, stove against cook time and max achievable cooking temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a solar oven? The kind that sits in the sun and is heated by the sun's rays with no electricity or other power source. For cooking it'd be more efficient than a PV system. Obviously it wouldn't work at night so it might not meet your needs.

Comment: What is the difference between Summer and winter sunshine? hot food in summer only?

Comment: Yeah, the summer/winter difference can be huge depending on where you live. Like I said, a solar cooker might not meet your needs, but it's an idea you could use during certain times of the year. Of course, if winter drops in solar output where you live are large enough to make a solar cooker not work then you'll probably have large drops in PV energy production as well. I'd go with a gas stove if you're relying on this for hot food in Winter.

Comment: Well, it is possible to plan for both - reduces the gas cost that way.